# Finding angle in an equilateral triangular pyramid

Tags: triangles

Given an equilateral triangular pyramid (refer the below diagram) $\Delta ABC$ & $P$ is any point inside the triangle such that ${PA}^{2}={PB}^{2}+{PC}^{2}$, then $\angle BPC$ is -

[image]

I am unable to think of how to do this question

Comment: This doesn't answer the question directly, but it might give you some good ideas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeiu%27s_theorem

Comment: Still No progress !!

Comment: Is the theorem linked with the question

Comment: There is an idea in the proof that you can apply here.

Comment: Which idea?? Can you tell me please

Comment: You may also want to take a look at this similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450424/find-the-side-length-of-triangle-abc/1450442#1450442

Comment: BUt the measurements are not given here

Comment: Hence why I said "similar" and not the same. The key point is that the lengths satisfy the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a complete solution. (I think)

Define an equilateral triangle on the coordinate system as follows:

$A=(0,{\sqrt3\over 2}),B=(0.5,0),C=(-0.5,0),P=(x,y)$

By the requirement of $P$$$y^2 +(x+0.5)^2+y^2+(x-0.5)^2=x^2+(y-{\sqrt3\over 2})^2$$$$\implies \left(y+{\sqrt3\over 2}\right)^2+x^2=1 $$

$\therefore$ The locus of $P$ is the circle with center $\left( 0,-{\sqrt3\over 2}\right)$ and radius $1$.

Let the center be $O$ So $\angle BPC=1/2(\angle BOC)=150^{\circ}$
( Knowing the coordinates of $ B;O;C$) Problem SOLVED!!

Comment: I like this approach, but your last sentence is off. Notice that $B$ and $C$ are also on this circle, so $\angle BPC$ is uniquely determined by the measure of the angle subtended from the arc going from $B$ to $C$.

Comment: @JoeyZou Thanks. I didn't notice

Comment: @JoeyZou  Problem Solved

Comment: @Amritanshu Check my solution

Comment: @Qwerty Can you generalize it ?

Comment: @ritwiksinha Generalise for what?

Comment: @Qwerty Without knowing the coordinates of the vertices.

Comment: @ritwiksinha i don't think. This property is that of an equilateral triangle, and I have **just placed it adequately** to make **calculations easy** If you    make the vertices more general , Calculations will be difficult. Try it on your own if you want to. I didn't want to make things unnecessarily cumbersome.

Comment: @Qwerty But evidence is not a proof. But i will surely try to do with general  equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: rotate the triangle $60^{\circ}$ clockwise around $B$, so that $A$ is rotated onto $C$, and let $P'$ be the image of $P$ under this rotation. Can you show the following statements:

1. $\angle PBP' = 60^{\circ}$
2. $\triangle PBP'$ is equilateral
3. $PP' = PB$
4. $P'C = PA$
5. $\triangle P'PC$ is a right triangle, with a right angle at $P$
6. $\angle BPC = \angle BPP' + \angle P'PC$

If you can show these statements, then the answer should follow.

Comment: can u upload an image too .... it then this question would be a piece of cake

Comment: @Amritanshu I agree an image would make the above statements quite clear, but unfortunately I can't make one right now. You're going to have to make it yourself. Sorry!

Comment: i am unable to understand the orientation of $P'$

Comment: [Here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Pompeiu.jpg) is a picture of what I mean. Notice that the entire triangle has been rotated $60^{\circ}$ clockwise, with $C$ rotated onto $A$, $A$ rotated onto $A'$, and $P$ rotated onto $P'$.